# python-telegram-bot cannot run because of: TypeError: Application.add_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Just trying to get this telegram bot working but it boils down to an error in this line. Not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

```
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, filters

message_handler = MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & filters.Command,handle_message)

# Add the handler to the bot
from telegram.ext import Application

application = Application.builder().token(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN).build
Application.add_handler(handler=message_handler)

# Start the bot
application.run_polling()
```

Comment: `Application` is a class, and it looks like you're supposed to create an _instance_ of it, just like you did with `MessageHandler`.  But instead you're referring to the `Application` class directly.